# Circular dependency - is there a good design to eliminate

Tags: circular-dependency

I was writing some code and came across a scenario that I was thinking about doing a circular dependent class, which I have not done before. I then looked circular dependencies up and whether they are impermissible, and found that it is achievable but not desirable. But I have some dilemma regarding how to implement it without circular dependencies so I thought I should see if there are other suggestions available.

Imagine that you are building an index for a number of files, and those files have a number of attributes, including an attribute that records what files the particular file references.

Attempting to set up some classes mimicking such structure, I have written a number of classes.

1. `subClassA` includes defining attributes of a file, let's call this
   attribute set A
2. `subClassB` includes classification attributes of a file, let's call
   this attribute set B
3. `fileObject` is an object representing a file, and has one
   `subClassA` object and one `subClassB` object.
4. `fileSet` is an object representing a particular set of files, and
   is essentially a collection of `fileObject`s

As I was creating `subClassB`, I realized that the information **related to reference files** within `subClassB` is really just a simplified `fileSet` with limited `subClassA` information. Is it wise then to simply circular reference within `subClassB` a `fileSet` object? Or if that is a terrible idea, how should one go about storing the information? Technically, we can create another collection class object under `fileObject`that will store a bunch of `subClassA` objects, but I don't really favor that as I would need to duplicate certain functions of `fileSet` within that new class definition (for example, functions that checks those objects, combines those objects, and etc).

And if I do it where I have an `object_M` that includes a collection of `subClassA` and another `object_N` that includes a collection of `subClassB` (that has an `object_M` included), and a top level `fileSet` that includes one `object_M` and `object_N`, that will solve the problem, but we suddenly got a new problem of needing some way to link the objects within `object_M` and `object_N` together somehow, another complexity in itself.

With the given scenario, should I just go with circular dependency? Or is there a better way to do it altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Circular relationships exist in the world, so if your object model is to accurately reflect such a relationship, the model must have circular logical relationships as well. There is nothing wrong with this.

The issue arises in the case of circular *references*, as a matter of implementation, not design. An object graph that cycles unto itself may have issues with the language's disposal mechanism, e.g. in the COM universe, which uses reference counting, the objects will never dispose, resulting in a memory leak.

The simplest way to avoid this is to use identifiers instead of object references. For example, instead of

```
class FileSet: List<File>
```

You might use

```
class FileSet : List<int>

class File
{
    public int UniqueID { get; }
}
```

And then give each `File` instance a unique integer identifier. When you need to find the files themselves, you can use the identifiers to select them via their identifier (e.g. as an index into an array) rather than by an actual memory reference. This design will never have circular object references-- because there are no object references to begin with.

As long as you take care of the implementation details diligently, there is absolutely nothing wrong with circular logical dependencies in your design.

Answer (score 0):

For me this sounds like [Analysis_paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) while trying to arrange classes in a **technical manner** like fileObject, AttributeClass, ....

If you approach your design from a **usecase perspective**. The design may become much more clear. Example:

- class fileObject=> JpegPhoto
- class subClassA => java File containing lastModifiedDate
- class subClassB => JpgExifInfo containing photo-tags
- class fileSet => Photoalbum

> As I was creating subClassB, I realized that the information 
>   related to reference files within subClassB is really just fileSet

would become

As I was creating JpgExifInfo, I realized that the information related to reference files within JpgExifInfo is really just Photoalbum

You probably tried to implement Search-Photo-By-Tag in the JpgExifInfo-class creating a circular reference.

If you implement Search-Photo-By-Tag in a seperate class PhotoCollection the circular reference is gone.

JpgExifInfo should not need to know what a Photoalbum is but a Photoalbum and a PhotoCollection may know what JpgExifInfo is.

- PhotoCollection contains one or more Photoalbum-s
- Photoalbum contains one or more JpegPhoto-s
- JpegPhoto contain File and JpgExifInfo
- File contains path and last modified
- JpgExifInfo contains on or more search-tags/categories. Searching for a photo by tag should be handled outside JpgExifInfo (i.e. in PhotoCollection)

Comment: Appreciate your comments! So, actually, the issue with doing what you said, implementing PhotoCollection and Photoalbum separately will work but will require me to either take some functions outside of the class so that they work on the objects directly, or to duplicate those class functions within those two classes. The scenario I have is more like various standard documents that can cite other standards, whereas Exif info really does not directly pertain to a file itself. Will that change your thoughts regarding how I should implement it?